# Why am I not able to create a data frame with correct values when combining 2 dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have 2 `dataframes`. I want to combine them

`dataframe 1` has columns `content` and `embeddings`

```
myquerycontents_and_embeddings_df.content
0                           i live in space
1                 i live my life to fullest
2                       dogs live in kennel
3        we live to eat and not eat to live
4    cricket lives in heart of every indian
5                         live and let live
6                  my house is in someplace
7            my office is in someotherplace
8                              chair is red
Name: content, dtype: object


myquerycontents_and_embeddings_df.embeddings
0    [0.0016913715517148376, -0.013320472091436386,...
1    [-0.01872972585260868, -0.010366685688495636, ...
2    [8.654659177409485e-05, -0.024498699232935905,...
3    [-0.024393899366259575, -0.008192254230380058,...
4    [-0.021614402532577515, -0.006505827885121107,...
5    [-0.01553483959287405, -0.014875221997499466, ...
6    [0.002573014236986637, -0.005427114199846983, ...
7    [0.013354390859603882, -0.007010389119386673, ...
8    [0.00505671463906765, -0.00909961387515068, -0...
Name: embeddings, dtype: object
```

`dataframe2` has column `cosinesimilarity`

```
similarityvaluedf.cosinesimilarity
0    0.994341
1    0.808836
2    0.818914
3    0.727792
4    0.675430
5    0.802331
6    0.849596
7    0.778798
8    0.776794
Name: cosinesimilarity, dtype: float64
```

I want to create a new `dataframe` which has 3 columns and 8 rows but I am getting `NaN`

```
combineddf = pd.DataFrame((myquerycontents_and_embeddings_df.content,myquerycontents_and_embeddings_df.embeddings,similarityvaluedf.cosinesimilarity),columns=['content','embeddings','cosine_similarity'])
combineddf
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
data = {
    'content': myquerycontents_and_embeddings_df.content.to_list(),
    'embeddings' : myquerycontents_and_embeddings_df.embeddings.to_list(),
    'cosine similarity': similarityvaluedf.cosinesimilarity.to_list()
}
combineddf = pd.DataFrame(data)
combineddf
```